# Find conditions on a,b,c and d in matrix B that commute with both matrices C and D

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having trouble here:

Find conditions on a,b,c, and d such that 
B =  \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\\ \end{bmatrix}

commutes with both \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}

I understand that for a matrix to commute AB = BA, but I don't know how to work with two distinct matrices. Would it be setting up four equations like:

\begin{bmatrix} a+0b & 0a+0b\\0c+0d&0c+0d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a+0c & b+0d\\0a+0c&0b+0d\end{bmatrix}

Sorry about formatting. Very new here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the first matrix first. You get
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &0\\0& 0\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &0\\0& 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right]$$
or
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a &0\\c& 0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a &b\\0& 0\end{array}\right].$$

Since all entries have to match up, we must have $a=a$, $b=0$, $c=0$, and $0=0$. The only informative equations here are $b=0$ and $c=0$.

Now, if you repeat the above for the second matrix, what do you get?

Comment: Okay, for the second matrix I came up with: \begin{array}{cc}0 &b\\0&d\end{array}=\begin{array}{cc}0 &0\\c& d\end{array}

Comment: so then we equate the first equation with the second? CD = DC?

Comment: I'm getting that a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, and d = 1

Comment: Why are you getting anything for $a$ or $d$?

Comment: For the second matrix the equations are 0 = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = d, so b = 0 and c = 0 are the informative equations. This means that in order for a matrix to commute with these two matrices it must be the identity matrix or a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call [ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) ]

and [ U = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) ]

and [ V = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) ]

All you have to do is to use the fact that AU = UA (A commutes with U) AND that AV = VA (A commutes with V) at the same time.

This leads to b = c = 0.

Comment: Apparently MathJax does not support `\[` and `\]`. Use `$$` instead.